# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on ubuntu32bit

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

After compiling the given program with gcc compiler, I tried to run this program on my ubuntu machine but instead I got an error message : **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**, however when I compile/run the same program on devc++ on my windows machine it works perfectly. Any idea please ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof( char *str)
{
    char buffer [24];
    strcpy(buffer , str);
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile ;
    badfile = fopen (" badfile ", "r");
    fread(str , sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);
    printf(" Returned properly \n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Undefined Behaviour - may work, may crash, may destroy the Universe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're copying from `str` which can be up to 517 bytes in size to `buffer` which is only 24 bytes in size.

So if the string you read in is longer than 24 bytes, you're copying off the end of `buffer` into memory that doesn't belong to it.  That is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means the program could crash, it could appear to work fine, or it can display other seemingly random behavior.

You need to make sure you don't overwrite the bounds of your array:

```
// first zero out the buffer, since strncpy doesn't necessarily NULL terminate
memset(buffer, 0 sizeof(buffer));
strncpy(buffer, str, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
```

EDIT:

As iharob, mentioned, the data being read in from the file is not being NULL terminated, so calling `strcpy` could read off the end of `str`.  So you need to address that as well:

```
int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile ;
    badfile = fopen ("badfile", "r");
    if (!badfile) {
        perror("fopen failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    // read in 1 byte less than the buffer size, and capture the return value
    int len = fread(str , sizeof(char), sizeof(str)-1, badfile);
    if (len == -1) {
        perror("fread failed");
        fclose(badfile);      // don't forget to close on error
        exit(1);
    } else {
        // add the NULL terminator
        str[len]='\0';
    }
    bof(str);
    printf(" Returned properly \n");
    fclose(badfile);       // don't forget to close
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I have changed the size of buffer to 517, still I get the same error message

Comment: @sasuke There is no room for the terminating `nul` byte, note that it's a very peculiar number `517`, where did it come from? If it's the number of characters in the file, you should make the buffer `518` bytes in order to store the `'\0'` terminator and add it like `str[517] = '\0'` otherwise `strcpy()` will cause undefined behavior and hence it could crash.

Comment: @sasuke Glad we could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.